# mean of sample vs the sample mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, mean

Say I have a sample population **A** it has mean $\mu_A$.  I sample **A** and obtain another sample population $\hat A$, it has a mean of $\mu_\hat A$.

If a hypothesis test indicates that I should be 95% confident that the two means $\mu_A$ and $\mu_\hat A$ are not equal.

What can I infer about $\hat A$ ?
How might it be different from **A**.

Comment: You might want to rethink how you describe the hypothesis test.  You probably mean "There is a 0.05 or less probability that if the two means were equal we would see the data we did", which is not the same?

Comment: @PeterEllis I am saying that 95% of the time I expect the difference in the means not be equal to 0. Is that not what I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be describing the procedure of [the bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) which allows you to estimate the standard deviation of a measured statistics (in your case the mean of the series) by sampling the series many times with replacements.

**By performing bootstraping you will be able to infer the distribution of μA** (it's standard deviation, or any of it's relevant CI).

Comment: Ok this'll give a framework to think about it, but I'm still having trouble fleshing out the implications. Care to speculate?

Comment: Can you explain what you are looking for? What would you like to learn about population A? and it's  μA?